# Antd Affix offsetBottom={50} not doing anything

Tags: reactjs, antd, affix

I have a system like [this](https://ant.design/components/affix/):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Affix, Button } from 'antd';

const Demo: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: '5000px' }}>Tall Table</div>
      <Affix offsetBottom={50}>
        <Button type="primary">
          Affix bottom
        </Button>
      </Affix>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Basically, I have a super long table which stretches beyond the viewport. However, adding the `Affix` doesn't appear to be doing anything. How do I get the `Button` to be at the bottom of the the browser viewport, until we scroll to the bottom of the table (whereafter it is below the table)?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-panini-ku9r4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hmm, something must be wrong in my system then, not sure why it's not working...